# Front-Ending an app server on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have 2 instances set up in EC2.  One is running nginx and has an association with the elastic IP address, so its publicly accessible.

The other doesn't have a web server but has a RESTful server running on port 8080.

Both belong to a security group with these rules:

```
Ports   Protocol    Source  MongoDB-2-2-2-AutogenByAWSMP-
22  tcp 0.0.0.0/0   
80  tcp 0.0.0.0/0   
8080    tcp 0.0.0.0/0
```

If I understand that right then port 8080 should be open.

If I ssh onto my web box (with nginx running) I'm trying to test access to my RESTful server on the other instance:8080, so I tried:

```
curl http://10.151.87.76:8080/1/tlc/ping
curl http://ip-10-151-87-76:8080/1/tlc/ping
curl http://ip-10-151-87-76.ec2.internal:8080/1/tlc/ping
```

All of these gave me "couldn't connect to host" errors.

If I log onto the RESTful box directly and do the following, it works.

```
curl localhost:8080/1/tlc/ping
```

So I know my service is up and healthy.

Any ideas why I can't see port 8080 from the other instance are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Make sure your headless service is publicly available << so this is the reason. What web server are you using for REST API? If it is Apache, make sure config says Listen 8080, not Listen 1.2.3.4:8080. If it is standalone app, make sure it can listen on all interfaces -- some clients will listen on localhost by default. – hudolejev 54 mins ago

This!  Buried deep (deep) within my code was a piece of the server wired to "localhost".  Changed that to key off hostname and all was well!  Happy.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure instances are in the same availability zone. If not, you may need to access the instance by public DNS name (something like ec2-XXX-XX-XXX-XXX.YYY.amazonaws.com).

Make sure 10.151.87.76 is the correct IP. Note that this will probably change after the instance is stopped and started again.

Make sure your headless service is publicly available -- it may listen on localhost:8080 only but should listen on 0.0.0.0:8080. Try `nmap 10.151.87.76 -p 8080` from other instance, it should list 8080 as open port.

Comment: Same availability zone: Yes

IP Check: These are correct

nmap said this:

Nmap scan report for ip-10-151-87-76.ec2.internal (10.151.87.76)
Host is up (0.00053s latency).
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
8080/tcp closed http-proxy

So it is closed on the web box even though the security policy said it was supposed to be open.  How to I overcome this?

Comment: > Make sure your headless service is publicly available << so this is the reason. What web server are you using for REST API? If it is Apache, make sure config says `Listen 8080`, not `Listen 1.2.3.4:8080`. If it is standalone app, make sure it can listen on all interfaces -- some clients will listen on localhost by default.

Comment: nmap `state=closed` means that port is open in firewall but no service is running. If it were closed in firewall, the result would be `state=filtered`.

Comment: Instead of 'some clients' I actually meant 'some servers' (: